# How to create and attach rows to this DataGridView?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

I'm beginner in .Net ,so maybe my question will seem naive to some of you.

I have DataGridView table in WinForm project: 
[image]

It contain three columns(image,combobox and textBox columns).

Any idea how to create and attach rows to this table?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Where is your code that you used to create the DataGridView..? what type of data do you want to Bind to this DataGridView? are you wanting to get the data from a Database? from a Collection, ..etc

Answer (score 1):

You create a data source, then bind the data source to the grid's DataSource property. You then add a record to your data source.

```
// create data source
BindingList<Shape> dataSource = new BindingList<Shape>();

// add record to data source
dataSource.Add(new Shape("Some Contour", "Circle", "Some Name"));

// bind data source
yourDataGridView.DataSource = typeof(BindingList<Shape>);
yourDataGridView.DataSource = dataSource;
```

Set the DataPropertyName of each column to matches the names of the fields in your Shape class.

```
DataGridViewTextBoxColumn colName = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
colName.DataPropertyName = "Name";

yourDataGridView.Columns.Add(colName );
```

However, I recommend you use [Virtual Mode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2b177d6d.aspx) instead to keep your data separate and decoupled.

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to accept inputs from user, you have to create a form on this page using which the user can provide inputs. Take those values and add them to a DataTable. Following is a sample snippet showing it:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("Contour",typeof(string));  //I am assuming that you will store path 
                                           //of image in the DataTable
dt.Columns.Add("Shape",typeof(string));
dt.Columns.Add("Name",typeof(string));
```

Keep adding new rows to the DataTable as you receive inputs from the user:

```
DataRow row = dt.NewRow();
row["Contour"] = txtContourPath.Text;
row["Shape"] = ddlShape.SelectedValue;
row["Name"] = txtName.Text;
dt.Rows.Add(row);
```

Assign above DataTable to DataSource property of the GridView.

```
dgv.DataSource = dt;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use method:

1. dataGridView1.Rows.Insert(...)
2. dataGridView1.Rows.Add(...)
3. Jay's answer : use dataGridView1.DataSource = dataSource;

Hope I can help you.